# Make pandas data usable by df functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I made a extracted a table from a website using pandas in python. I am trying to work with specific columns and cells within the table but I keep receiving the following error:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 df.iloc(5)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

This happens for every df.(insert function) that I have tried with this data. Is there a way to correct this error?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to put at least a screenshot or output of your data into the question!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not a dataframe, but a list. try putting the table inside of pd.DataFrame first and then use the functions. Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(listname).
```

Then

```
df.iloc[5] #or whatever function you wish to use
```

Note: pd is the reference to the pandas module.